# .htaccess issue with rerouting to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have this in my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.clipboards\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L=301]
```

These condition are working fine with one exception.
If I come from http (non-ssl) it will add index.php?*route* to my url before sending it to https. This is not the case if I come directly from https in which case it works fine. Can someone help me with this. thanks

Comment: Are you trying to enforce www also or something? What is the purpose of the last rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your redirects at the top and you can combine the bottom 2 rules. Also note that you have invalid syntax `[R,L=301]`, it should be `[R=301,L]`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```